# TASM - Symbols in front of the "Hello World" output

Tags: assembly, tasm

My code is:

```
.model tiny
.data
message: db "Hello World $";
.code
org 100h
main proc near
mov dx, offset message
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 00
int 21h
endp
end main
```

But in the output I get (screenshot). Where are these symbols come from? Thank you.
[image]

Build it with:

> tasm hello.asm
>
> link hello.obj
>
> (default enters)

Comment: Probably need to set the segment registers.  If you debug it, you'll find that `offset message` captured in `dx` doesn't refer to the location of label `message:`.

Comment: Please include the commands you use for building your program.

Comment: Erik, yes, because of some reason it shows "mov dx, <addr>", but in ds there is no "message" in this address.

Comment: Erik, but isn't .model tiny solves problem with segment registers?

Comment: You have to run `exe2bin` on the resulting `.exe` file, then rename the generated `.bin` file to have a `.com` ending. I used the free (but lacking source code) tool from the 2018 MS-DOS v2 release, which you can get at https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/msdebug/file/62d3a72c1915/exe2bin.exe (click the "raw" link to the side to download it). Or use a public domain tool with NASM sources, in https://pushbx.org/ecm/download/x2b.zip from repo at https://hg.pushbx.org/ecm/x2b I tested this, too.

Comment: ecm, thank you, default tasm exe2bin worked.

Comment: @ErikEidt: This is source for a `.com` executable, which gets loaded at offset `100h` with all segment registers already set correctly, equal to each other (`.model tiny` tells the assembler to assume that).  You should *not* modify `ds` in a `.com` executable.  It seems the OP's problem is linking it into something other than a `.com`, like a `.exe` apparently.  With NASM you'd just use `nasm -f bin` to assemble into a flat binary.

Answer (score 3):

You are using memory model "tiny" and `org 100h` as for COM executable format but link MZ executable.
Pass `/t` flag to the linker:

```
tasm hello.asm
tlink /t hello.obj
```

It creates `hello.com` with correct memory layout.

If you want MZ executable format (EXE) then specify for example `.model small`, define stack segment and load `ds` register with data segment.
`message` must be variable, not a label (no `:` after name).

```
.model small

.stack

.data
message db "Hello World $"

.code
main:
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov dx, offset message
mov ah,09h
int 21h
mov ah, 4ch
mov al, 00
int 21h
end main
```

Link with `tlink hello.obj`. It creates `hello.exe`.